# HtmlUnit first steps

Tags: java, classpath, htmlunit, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to set up my first example program with HtmlUnit. This is the code:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;


public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    HtmlPage currentPage = client.getPage("http://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer");
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
    String textSource = currentPage.asXml();
    System.out.println(textSource);

}

}
```

then i compile:

> javac -cp lib/htmlunit-2.9.jar test.java

but when i try to exec test i get

> java -cp lib/htmlunit-2.9.jar test
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
>   Could not find the main class: test. Program will exit.

where is the problem? i lack some other packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

> java -cp .:lib/* test

Answer (score 4):

you may have to add the current path to the classpath.

On Unix/Linux/Mac:

```
java -cp .:lib/htmlunit-2.9.jar test
```

On Windows:

```
java -cp .;lib/htmlunit-2.9.jar test
```

**EDIT**
There is actually more jars needed for htmlunit that just htmlunit-2.9.jar. Therefore, considering that all those required jars are located in the lib/ directory, you should actually invoke the following:

On Unix/Linux/Mac:

```
java -cp .:lib/* test
```

If you run this command from  a shell, you also need to escape the wildcard (with a '\')  or put the whole classpath within quotes to avoid shell expansion.

On Windows:

```
java -cp .;lib/* test
```

Comment: Ok, after looking around I found out why your problem was not solved by this line. It is because you have more than a single jar in htmlunit. Therefore, you actually need to list them all or use a wildcard in your path.